# Finite Dimensional Complex Vector Space V with $dim(V)=1$ has an Upper Triangular Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am aware this is a very simple question, however, I feel I may be missing something obvious here. I am trying to understand the proof of the following statement:

Suppose V is a finite-dimensional complex vector space and $T \in L(V)$ is a Linear operator on V. Then T has an upper triangular matrix with respect to some basis of V.

The first step of the proof proceeds "We will induct on the dimension of V. Clearly the result holds for $n=1$". Why is it true for $n=1$? My thoughts are as follows. If $dim(V)=1$ then there exits some basis of $V$ of length 1, call it $z$. Then the matrix with respect to this basis will be $M(T)=[cz]$ for some complex scalar $c$. If $M(T)$ isn't upper triangular then $cz=0$ so either (1) $c=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $Tz=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $z=0$ which is a contradiction as z is a basis so can't equal zero. (2) $z=0$ which is a contradiction as $z$ is a basis. Is there a more simple argument that I am missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Any linear operator $T$ on $V$ with dimension one can be written as $T(x) = T(1)x$ and you can view $T(1)$ (a scalar) as an upper triangular matrix.

Comment: For this to be an upper triangular matrix don't we require $T(1) \neq 0$?

Comment: No. The matrix of zeros is upper (and lower) triangular.